Problem while trying to connect on a Spark Cluster hosted on a Docker container with Pyspark
I created a Docker container to run Spark and it is working on localhost:9090/. The problem is I can't create a Spark Cluster on my local machine to run on this cluster.


The error I get is:

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling
o26.applyModifiableSettings. : java.lang.IllegalStateException:
LiveListenerBus is stopped.

Dockerfile
FROM python:3.11-bullseye as spark-base

ARG SPARK_Version=3.4.0

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        sudo \
        curl \
        vim \
        unzip \
        rsync \
        openjdk-11-jdk \
        build-essential \
        software-properties-common \
        ssh && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
ENV SPARK_HOME=${SPARK_HOME:-"/opt/spark"}
ENV HADOOP_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME:-"/opt/hadoop"}
RUN mkdir -p ${HADOOP_HOME} && mkdir -p ${SPARK_HOME}
WORKDIR ${SPARK_HOME}

RUN curl https://dlcdn.apache.org/spark/spark-3.5.1/spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3.tgz -o spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3.tgz \
 && tar xvzf spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3.tgz --directory /opt/spark --strip-components 1 \
 && rm -rf spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3.tgz

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

ENV PATH="/opt/spark/sbin:/opt/spark/bin:${PATH}"
ENV SPARK_HOME="/opt/spark"
ENV SPARK_MASTER="spark://spark-master:7077"
ENV SPARK_MASTER_HOST spark-master
ENV SPARK_MASTER_PORT 7077
ENV PYSPARK_PYTHON python3



RUN chmod u+x /opt/spark/sbin/* && \
    chmod u+x /opt/spark/bin/*

ENV PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/:$PYTHONPATH

COPY entrypoint.sh .

ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]

Docker-compose
version: '3.8'

services:
  spark-master:
    container_name: da-spark-master
    build: .
    image: da-spark-image
    entrypoint: ['./entrypoint.sh', 'master']
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8080" ]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 3
    volumes:
      - ./book_data:/opt/spark/data
      - ./spark_apps:/opt/spark/apps
      - spark-logs:/opt/spark/spark-events
    env_file:
      - .env.spark
    ports:
      - '9090:8080'
      - '7077:7077'


Please share the docker container (link to container from registry or docker build file) so that the community can provide specific responses to solve your problem based on your docker setup.
